# Hibernate : Not able to create table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Here is my code :

UserDetails.java

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Entity
public class UserDetails implements ApplicationContextAware,BeanNameAware,InitializingBean,DisposableBean{

    @Embedded
    Address officeAddress;

    public Address getOfficeAddress() {
        return officeAddress;
    }

    public void setOfficeAddress(Address officeAddress) {
        this.officeAddress = officeAddress;
    }

    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        System.out.println("Enter in get home address");
        System.out.println(homeAddress.roomNumber + homeAddress.streetName);
        return homeAddress;
    }

    public void setHomeAddress(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }

    @Transient
    @Autowired
    Address homeAddress;

    @Column
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column
    String password;

    public String getPass() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPass(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column
    String adminName;

    public String getAdminName() {
        return adminName;
    }

    public void setAdminName(String adminName) {
        this.adminName = adminName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailID() {
        return EmailID;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        EmailID = emailID;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Column
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    String EmailID;

    @Column
    String date;

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        System.out.println(beanName);

    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("initialising bean called from after properties set");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("disposable bean distroy method");

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void myDestroy(){
        System.out.println("Pre Destroy method from annotation");       
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterConstruct(){
        System.out.println("called after construction from annotation");
    }

}
```

Code to save my object in DB

```
@GET
@Path("/signup/")
public Response responseMsg(@QueryParam("name") String name,
        @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("email") String email,
        @QueryParam("date") String date, @QueryParam("pass") String pass) {

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    UserDetails user = (UserDetails) context.getBean("user");

    Address addr = (Address) context.getBean("officeAddress");

    user.setOfficeAddress(addr);

    user.setEmailID(email);
    if (name.length() != 0)
        user.setName(name);
    user.setDate(date);
    user.setPass(pass);

    session.save(user);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();

}
```

spring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd                           
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="user" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.UserDetails"
        autowire="byName">

        <property name="adminName" value="Root"></property>
        <property name="name" value="Sparsh"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="officeAddress" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.Address">
        <property name="roomNumber" value="${roomNumber}"></property>
        <property name="streetName" value="office"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="homeAddress" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.Address">
        <property name="roomNumber" value="1"></property>
        <property name="streetName" value="home"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>
                    message
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.DisplayBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.DisplayBeanFactory" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="variable.properties" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey" 
        /> -->
        <bean name="loggingaspect" class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.AspectClass"/>
</beans>

hibernate.cfg.xml

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

error facing :

```
 Apr 24, 2015 12:55:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'test.userdetails' doesn't exist

Apr 24, 2015 12:55:55 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'test.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2767)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3278)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    at com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.HelloWorldREST.responseMsg(HelloWorldREST.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 60 more

Apr 24, 2015 12:55:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-helloworld-serlvet] in context with path [/JAXRS-HelloWorld] threw exception
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'test.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2767)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3278)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    at com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.HelloWorldREST.responseMsg(HelloWorldREST.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.userdetails' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 60 more
```

so error is that table does not exist.

but not able to understand the reason

see in my hibernate.cfg.xml i have

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

which should be responsible to create the table.

Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that was the culprit.

cannot give it AUTO, while setting it of my own.

```
@Column
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    String EmailID;
```

removed the @GeneratedValue, now working fine.

might be helpful for someone later.